# bundle install error no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

When i try install gem in rails app show my this error :

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any idea as to why this is happening and how to fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: how you installed ruby, through rvm?

Comment: on rails console type `which ruby` command

Comment: when run this print:   /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: type command `gem list`, see if you have bundler

Comment: yes, installed. =>  bundler (1.8.2, 1.7.11)

Comment: Again print same error !  =>  bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

For me it was my path setting, as revealed by `rvm`

```
rvm list
```

output:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.6'.

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.6 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Before checking my `PATH`, I ran the suggested command:

```
rvm use ruby-2.2.6
```

After that, the `bundle` command worked just fine. I then located where my `PATH` had got corrupted, and fixed that.

Comment: Answering despite age of the thread, because it's the first hit when I searched for the same error message…